# Create a listener for every form submission in Liferay 7.2

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I want to create a listener for every form submission in my portal.

I create a form called "Test Form" and before (or after) liferay saves informations in local database I want to send the data form to external API (and do whatever is needed).
I was trying to accomplish this task by doing something similar to this:

```
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.ModelListenerException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.BaseModelListener;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.Layout;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.ModelListener;

@Component(immediate = true, service = ModelListener.class)
public class FormListener extends BaseModelListener<Layout> {

    @Override
    public void onBeforeCreate(Layout model) throws ModelListenerException {
        System.out.println(
            "About to create layout: " + model.getNameCurrentValue());

        model.setTitle("Title generated by model listener!");
    }
}
```

But change **Layout** for a class related to every form submission - something like **FormContent** or something like that. Would be posible to accomplish this with "onAfterSubmit" listener (or something like that) or there's a better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess that it will be FormInstanceRecord you need to listen to. Did not verify it

Comment: first of all , which forms app are you using ? DDL´s with the form view or the new forms app ?

Comment: Forms created by content. Admin users will develop their own forms via portal and my goal is - after form is published in portal - to get all data filled in all forms and integrate to other application. Something similar to this project that all users after created in liferay platform are integrated with CRM https://github.com/amusarra/liferay-crm-sample-integration

Answer (score 0):

You can do this frontend side like Marco Mercuri shows you but backend side ModelListener is your friend so you are on the right track. For this you probably need to watch for DDLRecord. Chances are you need both the ModelListener and MessageListener since the data might not be available realtime. As an example you can look here: https://github.com/jverweijL/auto-translator/tree/master/auto-translator-listener/src/main/java/com/liferay/demo/auto/translate

Comment: Yeap, I'd rather using backend strategies in this case. However, I struggled some days in this issue - and already on it :( and could not succeed. Tried this approach with DDLRecord entity, but not even import this model I was able. Should I inject any dependency for that or this should be availabe in kernel as Layour model?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do something whenever **any form** is submitted, you can just use a script with an event listener.

Create a Liferay theme: [Theme documentation](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-2/frameworks/-/knowledge_base/f/themes-introduction)

In your main.js file (or wherever you want) put a javascript/jQuery/... event listener on form submit, something like this:

```
$('form').on('submit',function(){
    //do what you need...
});
```

[jQuery event listener documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/)

PS

The code you wrote is a Model Listener on Layout (that are the pages of our site in Liferay "language"). The method `onBeforeCreate` you posted is executed just before a new page is created, so one time per page. It has nothing to do with forms and submit.

Comment: Yeap, this is probably a posible solution! But working with jquery and doing all this work in frontend looks like not the most elegant one.